# asp.net mvc 5 date picker in form without any model

Tags: asp.net

inside the page which is belong to other model and here I need only one input which should have date picker. I don't want I select type in model but here in html, is there any helper or library?

Comment: Just a suggestion. Why don't you use jQuery for **DatePicker**?

Comment: do I need any extra library or plugin for that

Comment: Yes. You will need to add jQuery files or library for that. It's simple and I'll posting it as an answer. Wait.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add required jQuery files or libraries as below for jQuery DatePicker: (If you are using bundling in ASP.NET MVC, then use the following. By the way, bundling means to add all jQuery or CSS files in a single class for optimization)

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css",
            "~/Content/jquery-ui.css"));
```

Or simply without bundling, you can do the following as well:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" 
 src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the head section:

```
<script >
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Then finally:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

For more, you can check the below links:

[Sample-jQuery-DatePicker-01](http://instinctcoder.com/asp-net-mvc-4-jquery-datepicker/)

[jQuery-Plugin-Samples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-plugins.htm)

[Sample-jQuery-DatePicker-02](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ee01e6/how-to-add-jquery-datepicker-in-mvc/)

Comment: don't know did not work, even edit the bundle config, layout and index still nto work

Comment: I think, try creating demo project and see what happens. In this case, don't use bundling. Simply use script tags in the head section.

Comment: did direct with out bundle I mean from the scrip in internet not worked in IE 8

Comment: Try using other browsers. It should be working in IE 8. Have you enabled JavaScript in the browser?

Comment: same even I create a blank page with,<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>

Comment: See the first tutorial carefully. There are some other files too. I've included another link. Check.

Comment: This looks like a good answer to a terrible, zero-effort question. Since the original post  appears to be a request for a library recommendation, it is likely to be closed as off-topic. On that basis it is probably a good idea to refrain from answering these, otherwise we'll just get more of the same!